# Expected values $E[W(1)W^2(2)]$ and $E[W^3(1)]$ for Wiener process

Tags: expected-value, brownian-motion, random-walk

I need to compute $E(W(1)W^2(2))$

$$W(1)W^2(2) = W(1)(W(2)-W(1)+W(1))^2 $$
$$= W(1) \left[(W(2)-W(1))^2 + 2(W(2)-W(1))W(1) + W^2(1) \right] $$
$$ = W(1)(W(2)-W(1))^2 + 2(W(2)-W(1))W^2(1) + W^3(1) $$
Therefore due to independence because $W(1)=W(1)-W(0)$
$$E(W(1)W^2(2)) = E[W(1)(W(2)-W(1))^2] + 2E[(W(2)-W(1))W^2(1)] + E[W^3(1)] $$
$$  E[W(1)]\cdot E[(W(2)-W(1))^2] + 2E[W(2)-W(1)]\cdot E[W^2(1)] + E[W^3(1)] $$
First addend is equal to 0 because $E[W(1)]=E[W(1)-W(0)]=0$ second one is also equal to 0 but i have no idea what to do with the third one. Should I also try to find increments.
What did I forget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E\left[ W^3(1) \right] = 0$, since $W(1) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ by definition of Wiener process, and if $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then
$$E \xi^k = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}= 0,$$
if $k$ is odd, since we integrate an odd function over the whole line in this case.

Comment: Thank you. On the other hand if k is even I found we got $\sigma ^k (k-1)!!$ is this right? Or we may have something different?

Comment: @nodis6 Yes it's true.

Answer (score 0):

To show
$$\mathbb E\big[W_tW_T^2\big]=0$$
for $t\le T$ we can also use
Ito calculus to  get
\begin{align}
W^2_T&=2\int_0^TW_s\,dW_s+T\,,\\
W_tW^2_T&=2W_t\int_0^TW_s\,dW_s+W_tT\,.
\end{align}
Now use the  the martingale
property to conclude that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\Big[W_t\int_0^TW_s\,dW_s\Big]=\mathbb E\Big[W_t\int_0^tW_s\,dW_s\Big]\,.
\end{align}
Finally, by the integration-by-parts formula,
\begin{align}
W_t\int_0^tW_s\,dW_s=\int_0^tW_s^2\,dW_s+\int_0^t\int_0^uW_s\,dW_s\,dW_u+\int_0^tW_s\,ds
\end{align}
of which all terms have expectation zero.